# Restricting Associations in Information Server

Tags: ibm-information-server

We have associations for product modelled as part of secondary spec multi occurring grouping attributes. All the edits are allowed at collaboration area level only and catalog views are read only. We want to restrict the users from deleting the occurrences of existing grouping associations and instead end dating the specific occurrence via End Date attribute inside the grouping set. Is there any way we can restrict the deletion of occurrences via UI? If we put any validation error in post process, even if it throws the error, the deletion would have already happened.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should not allow to save the item via arising a validation error in post process and user must reopen the item. Or you should implement copy of grouping attribute for editing in colarea. And if the some group is deleted from copy structure you can restore them from original groups in the post process script and arise the validation exception